# background geolocation ionic 3 not updating

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Background geolocation plugin for ionic isn't updating. The functionality I want is every 30 seconds ask the plugin for a lat lng value if available. The issue is, it's only giving me the values initially and then the background stops. The foreground is fine, it's really the background. Basically I'm not able to send the requests after the first initial send in the background.

gps.ts

```js
startTracking() {
  console.log("started tracking");
  const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    debug: false, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false
  };

  this.backgroundGeolocation
    .configure(config)
    .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.lat = location.latitude;
        this.lng = location.longitude;
        this.bearing = location.bearing;
        this.speed = location.speed;
        this.accuracy = location.accuracy;
        this.timestamp = location.time;
      });

      this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY
      this.backgroundGeolocation.stop();
    });

  this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
}

sendGPS() {
  this.optionsService.sendGPS(gpsData).subscribe(result => {});
}

stopTracking() {
  this.sendGPS();
}
```

app.component.ts

```js
constructor() {
  this.sendGPSStart();
  this.interval();
}

sendGPSStart() {
  this.locationTracker.startTracking();
}

sendGPSStop() {
  this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
}

interval() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.sendGPSStart();
    this.sendGPSStop();
  }, "30000");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at examples e.g [dnchia/Ionic3-Background-Geolocation](https://github.com/dnchia/Ionic3-Background-Geolocation/blob/master/src/providers/location-tracker/location-tracker.ts) you would configure the interval on the background, as well as the periodic foreground send

**gps.ts**

```js
startTracking(interval) {

    console.log('started tracking')
    const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
      desiredAccuracy: 10,
      stationaryRadius: 20,
      distanceFilter: 30,
      debug: false, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      interval: interval
    };
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
interval = 30000;

constructor() {
  this.sendGPSStart()
  this.interval()
}

sendGPSStart(){
  this.locationTracker.startTracking(this.interval);
}

sendGPSStop(){
  this.locationTracker.stopTracking();
}

interval() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.locationTracker.sendGPS();
  }, this.interval)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are bug reports about this on projects github:

See:
https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/548
and
https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/issues/539

The creator of the project suggests removing the splash screen plugin (cordova-plugin-splashscreen)

Answer (score 1):

I was using the plugin and after some reading i believe the beaviour

First you need to remove the line

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.stop()
```

from the code.

Second the background geolocation plugin due to IOS(and Android) restrictions is not executed whenever we want, but only when a 'Antena has changed event happens' So not only you need to really move as you need to connect and disconnect from carrier antennas, try applying this changes i said, turn the debug on, and go for a car ride just to test

Answer (score 0):

In your config, you must determine the interval in miliseconds.

```
const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
  desiredAccuracy: 10,
  stationaryRadius: 20,
  distanceFilter: 30,
  debug: false, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  interval: 2000 // <= example 2 seconds interval
};
```

Then in the subscribe section do a ajax call like

```
    this.backgroundGeolocation.on(BackgroundGeolocationEvents.location).subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {
          console.log(location);

          this.postData = {
            user_id: this.userId,
            latitude: location.latitude,
            longitude: location.longitude,
          };

          console.log(location);

          this.http.post<ActivationResponse>(environment.crmUrl + '/api/start-job', this.postData,
            { headers: new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: this.token }), observe: 'response' })
            .subscribe(async (response: HttpResponse<ActivationResponse>) => {

              console.log(response);
              this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

            }, async (errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {

              console.log(errorResponse);

            });
});
```

It will send new gps location to your determined server every 2 seconds automatically.

Answer (score 0):

All locations (even a single one) will be sent as an array of object(s), when postTemplate is jsonObject and array of array(s) for jsonArray!

In server-side, I changed the JSON object to an array of object.

For example,

```
{
  "user_id": "1",
  "lon": "13.2",
  "lat": "82.3"
}
```

I changed the above JSON object to following

```
[{
  "user_id": "1",
  "lon": "13.2",
  "lat": "82.3"
}]
```